# Advantage of a treebank in XML format

Tags: nlp, data-formats

Which treebanks are based on an XML format? 
What is the advantage of XML format for a treebank? I think it may have effects on annotation and querying the treebank.

for example [LASSY](http://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/Lassy/) and Alpino or TIGER are in xml format.

Comment: Can you give an example showing how using XML would affect the annotations?

Answer (score 1):

Extensible Markup Language (XML) is a way to encoding documents in a format that is both human-readable and machine-readable. It is also relatively simple and commonly used. It allows data and metadata to be linked. Those are the reasons that is often used for treebank data.